# How to map optical flow field (float) to pixel data (char) for image warping?

Tags: c++, c, graphics, image-processing, opencv

I've been playing with the optical flow functions in OpenCV and am stuck. I've successfully generated X and Y optical flow fields/maps using the Farneback method, but I don't know how to apply this to the input image coordinates to warp the images. The resulting X and Y fields are of 32bit float type (0-1.0), but how does this translate to the coordinates of the input and output images? For example, 1.0 of what? The width of the image? The difference between the two?

Plus, I'm not sure what my loop would look like to apply the transform/warp. I've done plenty of loops to change color, but the pixels always remain in the same location. Moving pixels around is new territory for me!

Update: I got this to work, but the resulting image is messy:

```
//make a float copy of 8 bit grayscale source image
IplImage *src_img = cvCreateImage(img_sz, IPL_DEPTH_32F, 1);
cvConvertScale(input_img,src_img,1/255.0); //convert 8 bit to float

//create destination image
IplImage *dst_img = cvCreateImage(img_sz, IPL_DEPTH_32F, 1);

for(y = 0; y < flow->height; y++){

    //grab flow maps for X and Y
    float* vx = (float*)(velx->imageData + velx->widthStep*y);
    float* vy = (float*)(vely->imageData + vely->widthStep*y);

    //coords for source and dest image
    const float *srcpx = (const float*)(src_img->imageData+(src_img->widthStep*y));
    float *dstpx = (float*)(dst_img->imageData+(dst_img->widthStep*y));

    for(x=0; x < flow->width; x++)
    {
        int newx = x+(vx[x]);
        int newy = (int)(vy[x])*flow->width;
        dstpx[newx+newy] = srcpx[x];
    }
}
```

I could not get this to work. The output was just garbled noise:

```
cvRemap(src_img,dst_img,velx,vely,CV_INTER_CUBIC,cvScalarAll(0));
```

Comment: optical flow gives you speed of each block of pixels in X or Y direction

Comment: Ok, so the float values returned from the flow maps are velocity values? Is that right? How is that velocity value applied to the pixel coordinates?

Comment: Each block consists of pixels, each pixel of a block shares block's speed. Use sizes of an image and resulting speed matrix to calculate pixel-block mapping

Comment: There are no "blocks", this is a dense optical flow algorithm, there is a velocity per pixel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The flow vectors are velocity values. If the pixel in image 1 at position `(x, y)` has the flow vector `(vx, vy)` it is estimated to be at position `(x+vx, y+vy)` (so the values aren't really in the `[0, 1]` range - they can be bigger, and be negative too). Easiest way to do the warping is to create floating point images with those values (`x+vx` for the x direction, similar for y), and then use `cv::remap`.

Comment: Ok, I took your advice and now I have it working on the X axis! I still need to figure out how to get the Y axis to update. And what is the purpose of using cvRemap()?

Comment: it's exactly the same in x and y directions, there is no reason one should "work" and the other not. and `cv::remap` does the warping. You shouldn't use `cvRemap` if you are using c++, as your tags say, opencv has a distinct c++ interface.

Comment: I updated the above post to show the code I am working with. I couldn't get cvRemap to work. I am using C syntax, the only reason I put C++ in the tags is because much of OpenCV is C++ based (I have to use g++ to compile).

Comment: opencv works perfectly fine with C only - you can compile things with gcc. If you have to use g++ to compile, that's for some other reason.

Comment: Sorry, let me clarify. The problem is I get a bunch of linker errors (Undefined symbols) if I set up Xcode to compile a C and not C++.

Comment: Also, I am unclear on your instructions. You say "Easiest way to do the warping is to create floating point images with those values (x+vx for the x direction, similar for y)," which effectively applies the warp because I am adding in the offsets from the flow maps. But then you also say to use cvRemap. Should I do both? Or one or the other? Thanks!

Comment: No, that doesn't apply the warp. I did not say "the pixel at x+vx" but just "x+vx", which is the input for remap. The opencv documentation is pretty extensive, you should at least try to understand it ... http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/STRAWMAN/c/geometric_image_transformations.html ... mapx and mapy are coordinates, not offsets. Flow gives you offsets, adding the original coordinate gives you the new coordinate.

Comment: I understand all this, however when I pass my X and Y maps to cvRemap(), all I get is either noise or the output from cvRemap looks exactly like the X input map (most of the motion is on the X axis). No shifting is occurring. I am using what was labeled as a "stable" SVN version of OpenCV. Could that be the problem? I don't see what else it could be, as I am passing float maps, per the documentation, to cvRemap, and 8 bit (tried 32F as well) single channel images as the image to be remapped and output. I am outputting the maps separately so I can check them, and they look correct.

Comment: No, you don't understand all this if what you are doing is `cvRemap(src_img,dst_img,velx,vely,CV_INTER_CUBIC,cvScalarAll(0));`. velx and vely are offsets, not coordinates.

Comment: Sorry, now I understand. What you said here made it finally click. It's working fine now! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Using OpenCV

https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/python/opt_flow.py

```
def warp_flow(img, flow):
    h, w = flow.shape[:2]
    flow = -flow
    flow[:,:,0] += np.arange(w)
    flow[:,:,1] += np.arange(h)[:,np.newaxis]
    res = cv2.remap(img, flow, None, cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
    return res
```

[image: Sample Result]